# Black screen in the beginning of installation process of Debian 7.8 on Hyper-V on Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-8.1, debian, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am trying to install Debian 7.8 using an ISO image "debian-7.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso" on Hyper-V.
When the VM is running, I see a graphical start screen:

[image]

When I choose the first command, I get simply a black screen. The installation does not continue.

When I was creating the VM, I chose generation 2.
There is the configuration file of the VM:

http://pastebin.com/XXCc3xc6

My PC configuration: CPU Core i7 950, 6 GB RAM, host OS is Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

Any advice would be welcome.

**UPD**
I turned secureboot off. It did not help. Finally I created a new virtual machine of gen 1 and successfully installed the OS.

Comment: try the first VM generation , not 2. V2 activates secureboot and UEFI. maybe debian has issues with it.

Comment: I turned secureboot off and it did NOT help. A VM of the Gen 1 is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [V2 Virtual Machine activates UEFI with Secureboot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn282285.aspx) and not all Linux distributions support this. Create a V1 machine, if turning off secure boot doesn't help.